# JSP, Spring framework - regular expression form validation

Tags: java, regex, spring, jsp

Is there a regular expression that can match 2 fields like:

If I had a password and confirm password field, Is there a regexp that can match the 2 fields before the form is processed?

Comment: Instead of regular expression, you have to just comapre two string in java if you want macth two field. Yes you can use regular expression to check the password strength.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want a regex for this? A regex is used to test if some string matches or contains an expression.

To do what you want, just use equals:

```
if (password.equals(passwordConfirmation)) {
    // proceed
}
```

It can't be much simpler.